# Что означает ошибка "DEP0001 : Unexpected error: -2147467259"?

Tags: c#, uwp

Сегодня не  могу запустить приложение на эмуляторе смартфона, выскакивает ошибка:

> DEP0001 : Unexpected error: -2147467259

При этом вчера все работало нормально. А сегодня запускается лишь на ПК.

Comment: Ошибка развертывания приложения. Эмулятор запускается? Ошибки при запуске эмулятора появляются?

Comment: @Vlad Эмулятор запускается. Вот что сообщает студия: There were deployment errors. Continue?
Если нажать Да, то выводится это:

The project "ProjectName" needs to be deployed before it can be started и т.д.

Comment: У меня была похожая проблема. К сожалению, четкого алгоритма решения у меня нет, т.к. перепробовал много вариантов. Вероятно, [этот](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29903619/windows-phone-emulator-not-starting-couldnt-setup-the-udp-port) ответ поможет. Возможно, нужно будет попробовать переустановить эмулятор, если решение в ответе не подойдет.

Comment: @Vlad К сожалению не помогли ни ответы, ни переустановка эмулятора. Я попробовал запустить старые версии приложения, но там та же самая ошибка. Систему переустанавливать? Хотя у меня такое было, но после нескольких отключений и включений все заработало. Сегодня этого не пробовал.

Comment: Систему я не переустанавливал. Помню, что переустанавливал эмуляторы и пользовался информацией из этого ответа. Еще на форумах советовали удалить предыдущую версию приложения из эмулятора. Но при переустановке эмулятора ее и так не должно быть.

Comment: @Vlad Ужас. В общем, удалил SDK и эмуляторы другой версии(не той, на которой я работаю) и заново установил. Теперь все работает.

Comment: Оформите свой комментарий как ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мне, хоть это и странно, помогла переустановка SDK и эмулятора другой версии Win10.